# Filter row sequence defined by values in several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe from which I want to filter/which I want to subset on **row sequences** fulfilling two conditions: (**EDIT**) (i) *the first row* in the sequence is `Q == "q_misc"` and (ii) *all rows* in the sequence `Seq` are not `NA`

```
df <- structure(list(Line = c(480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 497L, 
498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 557L, 558L, 
559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 564L), Seq = c(NA, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, NA, NA), Q = c(NA, "q_wh", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "q_misc", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "q_pol", NA, NA, NA, NA, "q_misc", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output is this row sequence:

```
   Line Seq      Q
8   498   0 q_misc
9   499   0   <NA>
10  500   0   <NA>
11  501   0   <NA>
18  558   0 q_misc
19  559   0   <NA>
20  560   0   <NA>
21  561   0   <NA>
22  562   0   <NA>
```

I've tried this but it only returns the first row of the row sequence:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Q == "q_misc" & !is.na(Seq))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `fill` to fill the missing values with previous value and select rows where value is `'q_misc'` and `Seq` is not `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Q1 = Q) %>%
  fill(Q1) %>%
  filter(Q1 == 'q_misc' & !is.na(Seq)) %>%
  select(-Q1)

#  Line Seq      Q
#1  498   0 q_misc
#2  499   0   <NA>
#3  500   0   <NA>
#4  501   0   <NA>
#5  558   0 q_misc
#6  559   0   <NA>
#7  560   0   <NA>
#8  561   0   <NA>
#9  562   0   <NA>
```

Comment: Ronak, thanks for this. It works for the mini df but not for the actual dataset. Please note I've edited the question providing some clarification. Maybe have a look ...

Comment: dear @Ronak, I've edited the data. Your code does not yet completely work with this sample. Can you have a look, please?

Comment: You can have a look at the updated answer and let me know if it works on your actual data @ChrisRuehlemann

Answer (score 2):

Using `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(zoo::na.locf0(Q) %in% 'q_misc', complete.cases(Seq))
  Line Seq      Q
1  498   0 q_misc
2  499   0   <NA>
3  500   0   <NA>
4  501   0   <NA>
5  558   0 q_misc
6  559   0   <NA>
7  560   0   <NA>
8  561   0   <NA>
9  562   0   <NA>
```

Comment: I'm ever so sorry: I counfounded the two `df`I used in my two questions posted to So today! Yes, your solution works beautifully! and I've upvoted it therefore. Apologies again!